# Can you give an understandable strategy to compute the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)\operatorname{Li}(n)}{n}$?

Tags: integration, summation, proof-writing, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

First I am looking a discussion about if the statements that I've deduced will find a good asymptotic formula, what of them you can discard as non useful,or one better than other, and ... second my main goal is obtain the asymptotic behaviour as $x\to\infty$ for
$$\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)\operatorname{Li}(n)}{n},$$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is **von Mangoldt function** and $\operatorname{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$ is the **logarithmic integral**, I don't know if this exercise is in the literature but I want to solve reasoning what strategies (basically analysis,  by summation, inversion formulas...these kind of tools, when I am looking to compute the asymptotic behaviour) and **unconditionally**, this is without assumption of conjectures and without special (high) methods in analytic number theory and too I want to know what is the meaning of research such solution, and it return us at the... *First*.

When I've used **Abel's summation formula** I can deduce two statements
$$\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}\cdot \operatorname{Li}(n)=(\log x)\cdot \operatorname{Li}(x)-(x-2)+O\left(\operatorname{Li}(x)\right),$$
here I've used a consequence of **Shapiro's Tauberian theorem** $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}=\log x+O(1)$, and it is know that $O\left(\operatorname{Li}(x)\right)=O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$. On the other hand $$\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\Lambda(n)\cdot\frac{\operatorname{Li}(n)}{n}=\psi(x)\cdot\frac{\operatorname{Li}(x)}{x}-\int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)}{t\log t}dt+\int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)\operatorname{Li}(t)}{t^2}dt,$$
here $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)$.

> **Question 1.** Now I am in the situation that I've used an asymptotic for $\operatorname{Li}(t)$ in the second integral of last identity, or perhaps I ask to me if is better that I should to use an asymptotic for the second Chebyshev function $\psi(t)$, further how I know that the first asymptotic identity is better or worse than the second that I'm theorizing now (I say the second)? **Can you discard some of these identities, one as baddest than the other one?**

My following question is to deepen in this my disorientation. I did and thought about some tools. I have the cited consequence of **Shapiro's theorem**, too perhaps I can use **Hölder's inequality** for $\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)\operatorname{Li}(n)}{n}$, where for example $a_n=\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}$ for $n>1$, and $b_n=\operatorname{Li}(n)$ if $n\geq 2$ and $b_1:=0$, and take $p=1+\epsilon$. Too I imagine and ask to me: could be useful **Selberg's asymptotic formula?** I say: why no?, if I don't know what I doing, I write for example as an easy deduction that I can relate with a previous identity, since these share summands
$$\int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)}{t\log t}dt+\int_{2}^x\frac{\sum_{n\leq t}\Lambda(n)\psi(\frac{t}{n})}{t\log^2 t}dt=2\operatorname{Li}(x)+O\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right),$$
and it is known that the logarithmic integral $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t}=O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2 x}\right)$.

> **Question 2.** I did these computations, and ask to you: **can you discard (using a mathematical reasoning,
> from a practical point of view and objective) these usages** of for example Hölder, Selberg or Shapiro?

The

> **Main Question.** How do you compute with a clear strategy the asymptotic behaviour as $x\to\infty$ of $$\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}\cdot \operatorname{Li}(n)$$
> without expensive methods in analytic number theory?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I believe that there is a mistake in the computation of the error term in the deduction from **Selberg's asymptotic formula**, since I take $\int O(something)=O(\int(something))$.

Comment: Thanks for the useful and detailed answer given by the **user**, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first application of the Abel's summation you get $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda\left(n\right)}{n}\textrm{Li}\left(n\right)=\left(\log\left(x\right)+O\left(1\right)\right)\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)-\int_{2}^{x}\left(\log\left(t\right)+O\left(1\right)\right)\left(\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)\right)'dt=
 $$ and now since $\textrm{Li}\left(n\right)=\frac{n}{\log\left(n\right)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log^{2}\left(n\right)}\right)
 $ we have $$=x+O\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right)-x+2+O\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right)=O\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right).
 $$ For the second application, we can use the asymptotic $$\psi\left(x\right)=x+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ and so we can get $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda\left(n\right)}{n}\textrm{Li}\left(n\right)=\frac{\psi\left(x\right)}{x}\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\psi\left(t\right)}{t\log\left(t\right)}dt+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\psi\left(t\right)}{t^{2}}\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)dt=
 $$ $$=\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)-\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)+O\left(\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log^{3}\left(t\right)}dt\right)+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)}{t}dt+O\left(\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)}{t\log^{2}\left(t\right)}\right).
 $$ Now observe that we have, integrating by parts, $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)}{t}dt=\log\left(x\right)\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)-x+2\tag{1}
 $$ so if we take again $\textrm{Li}\left(n\right)=\frac{n}{\log\left(n\right)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log^{2}\left(n\right)}\right)
 $ we'll get $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)}{t}dt=O\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ which is bigger than the other errors, since $$O\left(\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)=O\left(\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log^{3}\left(t\right)}dt\right)=O\left(\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)}{t\log^{2}\left(t\right)}\right)=O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{3}\left(x\right)}\right)\tag{2}
 $$ so in this case (and only in this, because in the first part we have $O\left(\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)\right)
 $ and so we are “forced” to $x/\log\left(x\right)
 $) we can use a better approximation for $\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)
 $. It is possible to prove, iterating the integration by parts, that $$\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k!}{\log^{k}\left(x\right)}+O_{n}\left(\frac{x}{\log^{n+2}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ so if we take $n=2
 $ we have $$\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}+\frac{2x}{\log^{3}\left(x\right)}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{4}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ and so if we apply this in $(1)
 $ we get $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\textrm{Li}\left(t\right)}{t}dt=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{2x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{3}\left(x\right)}\right)\tag{3}
 $$ and finally, by $(2)
 $ and $(3)
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda\left(n\right)}{n}\textrm{Li}\left(n\right)=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{2x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{3}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ which is a better result.

Comment: Very thanks much, I need some hours to read it. Very thanks much.

Comment: Very thanks much I need more days to understand all details and words in your good proof. The part that I have understood is very good.

Comment: @user243301 My pleasure. If you need some clarifications contact me ;)